# How to become a Data Scienctist

Tags: data

I have done part time MBA in SAP (SD & MM Module). I am very good in MS Excel (Certified MCAS from Microsoft) and Data Analysis. I have around 15 years of working experience in MIS & Dashboard. I have basic knowledge of programming but not an expert.
How can i become a Data Scientist with this qualification and experience?
Regards,
Hitesh Gaur

Comment: Have you googled "data science master" or "data science bachelor"?

Comment: This might be on-topic at [SE.Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) (though you may want to read the posting guidelines to check).

Comment: @Coder I don't know if this really is a shopping question. It doesn't ask for a particular program or degree, but rather about the educational pathways towards an emerging field.

Comment: @Coder This is not a shopping question, but it is off topic because it is not about academia.  This is a question about industry.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Data Science is still a novel field. Some might dispute whether it actually is a field in ints own right or rather an intersection of statistics, computer science, perhaps linguistics and quantitative methods (quantitative political science, sociology, or finance, econometrics, computational biology...). With the right specialization, enrolling in a program of any of these fields might give you the skills a data scientist needs. There are, however, also new dedicated data science bachelor and master programs popping up left and right. You have to compare several universities' websites to find the one best suited to your needs and interests.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer Monica.

Comment: @HiteshGaur They're not Monica. They're someone who's changed their name as a protest to a moderator named Monica being fired by StackExchange.